# VB 6 integration with OneNote

Tags: xml, windows-7, vb6, onenote

I have a vb6 application that interacts with OneNote 2010. I am testing the integration in win XP and Win 7. Some notebooks can exist on SkyDrive and those are no problem in either OS, they open via a browser. When creating a new notebook, it is creating it locally. this works fine in XP but calls an error in win 7:
"Runtime error "-2147213311 (80042001) M3thod UPdateHierarchy of object IApplication failed"
I am interpreting this as a OneNote error which means the XML is invalid. The XML is generated the same way regardless of the OS. Are there any differences with the Microsoft XML libraries between XP and 7? I have not been able to pinpoint what the issue is in win 7, any help would be appreciated. the XML and code follows:

Quincy Mutual Insurance Co. is the new notebook I am trying to create.

Win XP :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<one:Notebooks xmlns:one="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2010/onenote">
    <one:Notebook name="Personal" nickname="Personal" ID="{EB245BB4-63DA-404E-BB9F-447008E7BE52}{1}{B0}" path="https://d.docs.live.net/637f21528f6026bf/^.Documents/Personal/" lastModifiedTime="2012-09-04T20:12:40.000Z" color="#FFD869"/>
    <one:Notebook name="EMC Insurance Companies" nickname="EMC Insurance Companies" ID="{DBA316FE-5D42-445E-A356-7405E7DD9E12}{1}{B0}" path="https://d.docs.live.net/637f21528f6026bf/^.Documents/EMC Insurance Companies/" lastModifiedTime="2012-06-29T10:41:29.000Z" color="#9595AA"/>
    <one:Notebook name="Sentry Insurance Company" nickname="Sentry Insurance Company" ID="{8A4E905D-429E-491E-9FE5-856A10BE3CD7}{1}{B0}" path="D:\My Documents\OneNote Notebooks\Sentry Insurance Company" lastModifiedTime="2012-08-14T13:15:36.000Z" color="#BA7575"/>
    <one:Notebook name="Quincy Mutual Insurance Co" path="D:\My Documents\OneNote Notebooks\\Quincy Mutual Insurance Co"/>
</one:Notebooks>
```

Windows 7

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<one:Notebooks xmlns:one="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2010/onenote">
    <one:Notebook name="EMC Insurance Companies" nickname="EMC Insurance Companies" ID="{E68066FB-38A4-4190-B82F-0A9F322C29AF}{1}{B0}" path="https://d.docs.live.net/637f21528f6026bf/Documents/EMC Insurance Companies/" lastModifiedTime="2012-08-24T22:07:44.000Z" color="#9595AA"/>
    <one:UnfiledNotes ID="{C8E287E1-3EF2-464B-9ACB-F22B69A887A5}{1}{B0}"/>
    <one:Notebook name="Quincy Mutual Insurance Co" path="G:\Users\ROC\Documents\OneNote Notebooks\\Quincy Mutual Insurance Co"/>
</one:Notebooks>
```

-

```
    Private Function GetClientOneNoteNotebookNode(oneNote As OneNote14.Application,      ClientName As String) As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    ' Get the XML that represents the OneNote notebooks available.
    Dim notebookXml As String
    Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim elem As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim newNotebookPath As String
    Dim notebookNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim defaultNotebookFolder As String
    ' OneNote fills notebookXml with an XML document providing information
    ' about what OneNote notebooks are available.
    ' You want all the data and thus are providing an empty string
    ' for the bstrStartNodeID parameter.
    oneNote.GetHierarchy "", hsNotebooks, notebookXml, xs2010
    ' Use the MSXML Library to parse the XML.
    Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    If doc.loadXML(notebookXml) Then
        Set notebookNodeList = doc.documentElement.selectNodes("//one:Notebook[@name='" &  ClientName & "']")
        If notebookNodeList.Length = 0 Then


            'Get the default location for the notebooks
            oneNote.GetSpecialLocation slDefaultNotebookFolder, defaultNotebookFolder
            newNotebookPath = defaultNotebookFolder + "\\" + ClientName

   '          Dim notebookId As String
   '          notebookId = doc.Attributes.getNamedItem("id").Text


            'Create new notebook for cleint
            Set elem = doc.createElement("one:Notebook")
            elem.setAttribute "name", ClientName
            elem.setAttribute "path", newNotebookPath
            ' add new elelement to the document tree
            doc.documentElement.appendChild elem

    '           Set notebookNodeList = doc.documentElement.selectNodes("//one:Notebook   [@name='Personal']")
'           elem.setAttribute "path", defaultNotebookFolder



            oneNote.UpdateHierarchy doc.XML
        End If
        ' Close notebook
   '      oneNote.CloseNotebook notebookId, False
   '     ' Open notebook
   '      oneNote.OpenHierarchy newNotebookPath, "", notebookId, cftNone
        Set GetClientOneNoteNotebookNode = notebookNodeList

    Else
        Set GetClientOneNoteNotebookNode = Nothing
    End If
    End Function
```

Anyone have any ideas? or can anyone point me to a ressource? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think opening OneNote notebook in OneNote 2013 will change the schema, I was facing similar issue for my custom plugin

You can try following:

1. Open the troublesome notebook in Desktop OneNote 2010
2. Save the notebook as .onepkg archive file
3. Unpack the .onepkg archive file somewhere on your PC
4. Open the unpacked notebook in Desktop OneNote 2010

Ref: http://www.mobilenoter.com/blog/post/2012/08/13/MobileNoter-SE-OneNote-2013-Preview-issues.aspx

Comment: Thanks for replying, I read the information at the link you provided. Seems that is more specific to the 2013 version and opening existing notebooks in that version. My problem has to do with the initial creation of a new notebook (locally). The version of OneNote that i am using for both XP and win 7 is 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the path for xp has a space and for win7 has no spaces. Could that be the culprit?
Also, you don't have doubleslashes in your paths, you just have single slashes. Maybe that is it?